# getting error while installing install_tensorflow()

Tags: r, tensorflow

i am trying to install tensorflow in r library. when i try to install using

```
> library(tensorflow)
> install_tensorflow()
Preparing for installation (updating pip if necessary)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\ideapad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (18.0)
Installing TensorFlow...
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/02/e07e6ff277147aa52816215cc1b96d1acd1166411fc71356c6c3160760ca/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting h5py
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/2c/4572e2e495341e667c89b490ad18ea71a5f9e9fafca06109a9c7db22848b/h5py-2.8.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (2.3MB)
Collecting pyyaml
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/d4/d895fb7ac1b0828151b829a32cefc8a8b58b4499570520b91af20982b880/PyYAML-3.13-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (205kB)
Collecting requests
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/5f/2829276d720513a434f5bcbf61316d98369a5707f6128b34c03f2213feb1/Pillow-5.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (1.6MB)
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/6b/11530768cac581a12952a2aad00e1526b89d242d0b9f59534ef6e6a1752f/astor-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/1f/3da43860db614e294a034e42d4be5c8f7f0d2c75dc1c428c541116d8cdab/tensorboard-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/1c/7451288f896ce972a2d2112ed1d8106d3950a02afc5bddf307a1a5de3d73/grpcio-1.14.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/47/54baeff52b37be258dd97442f52d8a2a9c27c4af8fcbc5467827c5ae5eed/numpy-1.15.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow)
Collecting protobuf>=3.4.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/7d/1145805ef3ac475074f8d14d1c0512a79ef709ddfd35ca89c5fa4fc94065/protobuf-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting setuptools<=39.1.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/10/79282747f9169f21c053c562a0baa21815a8c7879be97abd930dbcf862e8/setuptools-39.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow)
Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/c9/6fdd990019071a4a32a5e7cb78a1d92c53851ef4f56f62a3486e6a7d8ffb/urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (150kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<1.10.0,>=1.9.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/7d/488b90f470b96531a3f5788cf12a93332f543dbab13c423a5e7ce96a0493/Markdown-2.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: termcolor, astor, werkzeug, numpy, markdown, six, setuptools, protobuf, wheel, tensorboard, grpcio, absl-py, gast, tensorflow, h5py, pyyaml, idna, urllib3, chardet, certifi, requests, Pillow
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\ideapad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.CSRRD7HKRKC3T3YXA7VY7TAZGLSWDKW6.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

then i got the following error

```
Error: Error 1 occurred installing tensorflow package
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\/Scripts/pip.exe" install --upgrade --ignore-installed "tensorflow" "h5py" "pyyaml" "requests" "Pillow"' had status 1
```

Can someone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its just because you don't have permission to save the module as it is in C drive. So, just do the following

1.Open the app as an administrator and then install it

or

2.follow [This](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/134) link. this can help